# Spring Boot duplicates logs

Tags: spring-boot, logging

In my project, Spring Boot by default writes logs into logs.log. I need to set the logs location. I've added into my configuration yaml this config:

```
logging:
  file: logs-directory/logs-file.log
```

After that, Spring Boot logs into default file "logs.log" and the same content into defined "logs-directory/logs-file.log" file. How to switch off default location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Boot upgrade to 2.5.2 resolved my problem.
Current log configuration in the application.yaml:

```
    logging:
      level:
        root: info
        org.springframework.web: error
        org.hibernate: error
      file:
        name: logs/example-app.log
```